# Creating large file with BufferedOutputStream takes a long time

Tags: java, file, bufferedinputstream

I have a file which is comprised of one serialized String object written to the start of the file followed by the raw bytes of the file I am attempting to extract.

Here is my code:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\Test.tst");
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
String string = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\ExtractedTest.tst");
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
while(fileInputStream.available())
{
  int i = fileInputStream.read();
  bufferedOutputStream.write(i);
}
bufferedOutputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
```

The code takes an unusable long time for large files (1.5 GB, for example). How can I speed up the code? Am I using the wrong classes?

Regards.

Comment: define `an unusable long time` - what time are you expecting?

Comment: Does it take a long time compared to making a file via 'mkfile', say ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need that I guess:

```
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
String string = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

... and your loop should look more like that:

```
final byte[] temp = new byte[1000];
while (fileInputStream.available() > 0){
 int i = fileInputStream.read(temp);
 bufferedOutputStream.write(temp, 0, i);
}
```

Comment: And remember about closing the fileInputStream :]

Comment: Say there was another object after the file and the first object was instead a long typed object representing the size of the file. Is it possible to siphon out the file? temp[1000] goes beyond the file boundary into the second object.

Comment: @DannyRancher I don't understand what you are saying but variable i stands for the number of bytes you want to write to the output stream. Maybe play with that OR explain more clearly what you want to achieve ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to finetune your application by changing the buffer size.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html

Here you have documented a version of the constructor with a buffer size.  Maybe you can use a big buffer (at expense of your memory usage, of course, be ready to increase your heap size too)

[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)